# Unicode data from NSData to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, nsstring, nsdata

So if I have NSData from an HTTP request, then I do something like this:

```
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This will result in null if the data contains weird unicode data ([title is from reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/ema6o/clickmeandthen_check_your_recently_viewedlinks/)):

```
{"title":"click..██me..and..then██________ ██check██_.your...██.__...██____ ██....██████████████....██____ ██████....██████....██████____ ██████████████████████____ ....██████████████████______ ........██..._recently....██________ ....██....viewed....links....██_____"},
```

How would I convert the data to a string?
Ideally, it would best if the string wasn't null so I could parse it as JSON, but even a lossy conversion is fine with me in these cases.

I'm not familiar with unicode (naive American I am), so any enlightenment about that would be a nice bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy and paste that text into a UTF-8 text file, read it with `dataWithContentsOfURL:` and convert it to a string with `initWithData:encoding:`, it works fine. The most likely explanation is that you are not getting valid UTF-8 data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get in contact with the API developer.